# Why is React Native debugger opening in x86 version of Chrome, and not arm64?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, google-chrome-devtools, arm64

I'm using react native with Expo/Hermes on a mac M1. When I open the app and hit "open debugger" it opens the debugger in an x86 version of chrome, which is extremely slow. Why is this happening?

I don't have that version of chrome installed, so I have no idea where it's coming from.

Chrome version installed: 120.0.6099.129 (Official Build) (arm64)

React native: 0.72.5

Expo: 49.0.10

Steps to reproduce:

1. run `npx expo run:ios --device`
2. App runs on device
3. Press m │ toggle menu
4. Press "Debug Remote JS" on device

Comment: Leave it, use `Flipper` for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

The x86 browser you see it's an `Embedded Chrome DevTools Panel`, that might be on your `node_modules`.

According to [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging) page on the docs:

> Hermes supports the Chrome debugger by implementing the Chrome
> DevTools Protocol. This means Chrome's tools can be used to directly
> debug JavaScript running on Hermes, on an emulator or on a physical
> device.

On the `Hermes Debugger/Expo` tab, the doc doesn't mention any other browser than Chrome, just specifically chrome. But, I managed to find a step-by-step procedure to set up remote debugging:

1. Access the debugger URL on your browser. Example: http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui
2. Open the Console using CMD + Shift + J.
3. Press CMD + D on Simulator and select "Debug JS Remotely".
4. Press CMD + R on Simulator.
5. Check the Console in the Browser.

This is now deprecated on react-native 0.73, but you're using 0.72.5, so it will work for now. And, it might still be slow, because it will use chrome for the debugging still.

If you want to do it the way the newer react-native versions intend to, or see how you can use safari to debug your app, you can follow the steps on [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/other-debugging-methods) page.

You might want to try `Flipper` and see if it is faster, but the docs say it uses the same chrome Devtools Panel too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but those steps didn't work. Where is the embedded version of chrome and how do I disable it?